# void* of a bool[] conversion to std::string

Tags: c++, type-conversion, void-pointers

I need to save some data and the only viable option is a `std::string`; so I get a bool array passed as a `void*`. Now I need to save it in a way that I can convert it into a `std::string` and be able read a `void*` to a `bool[]` from that exact string. Sadly I got lost in conversion.

```
f(const void* data, int length){

   bool** boolPointer = (bool**)(data);
   bool boolArray[length];

   for (int i=0; i<=length; i++){
       boolArray[i] = p[sizeof(bool)*i];
   }

   std::string s = (std::string&)boolArray;
}
```

I'm pretty sure the last line is no viable conversion, but that was my attempt.

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to a std::string? What kind of format should that std::string have? One does not simply convert something to a string.

Comment: You should do `for (int i=0; i<length; i++)` `<` instead of `<=`

Comment: @Ashot if anything, he should do `std::copy(boolPointer, boolPointer+length, &boolArray[0])`. But I don't see why that would be needed at all.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes sadly it is very late in the project and std::string is the interface to the data saving mechanism.

Comment: The important part is the format that the string should have. You don't just "convert to a string". You "build a string with a certain format".

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes :) `std::string serial( (char *) boolArray, (char *) ( boolArray + length ) );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
char f(bool b)
{
    return b ? '1' : '0';
}

int main()
{
    // let's just consider whatever is there in this uninitialized array
    bool buf[100];

    std::string s;

    // transform and copy (convert true to '1' and false to '0')
    std::transform(&buf[0], &buf[99], std::back_inserter(s), f);

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

If you are on C++11, you can use the following code snippet

```
int main()
{
    bool buf[100];

    std::string s;

    std::transform(&buf[0], &buf[99], std::back_inserter(s), [](bool const &b){ return b ? '1' : '0'; });
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `[](bool b) { return b ? '1' : '0'; }` ?

Comment: @Bartek Banachewicz: Initially wrote that and removed as I did not notice the C++11 tag :).

Comment: please take a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133649/186268

Comment: @Bartek Banachewicz: Ok, thanks. I stand corrected if that's what is the guidline.

Comment: thank you very much. not C++11 I'm afraid; I'll use the C++03 tag next time then?

Comment: why not &buf[100] ?   ..one pass the end ??

Comment: @qPCR4vir Or even `(buf, buf+100, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you could just open up your C++ book...

```
std::string f(std::vector<unsigned char> const& v)
{
    std::string temp;

    for (auto c : v) {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
            temp += (c & (1 << i)) ? '1' : '0';
        }
    }

    return temp;
}
```

That could probably be done even easier with something like `std::copy` or some other cryptic `back_inserter` thingy, but I wanted to keep it simple. Another option would be to use `std::bitset` or your own encapsulation, to get rid of ugly bit operations.

If you're forced by the devil to pass the data by `void*`, just convert it to vector:

```
unsigned char* begin = static_cast<unsigned char*>(data);
vector<unsigned char> v (begin, begin + length);
```

Please also note that if it's for serialization purposes, that representation will be hardly readable both by computer and a human. If it's meant to be read by computer, save it as binary without conversions. If it's meant to be read by humans, save it as hex characters (splitting every byte in half).

Comment: I am not sure if he is on C++11. at least not tagged so

Comment: @Chubsdad I am using the **current** standard, which happens to be C++11. If he needs to use *older* standard, he should tag it appropriately.

Comment: If I have got it right, c++11 is the tag to be used for questions pertaining to new C++ standard

Comment: @Chubsdad that would make an awful load of questions tagged inappropriately. Anyway, it's fairly easy to convert the example to C++03.

Comment: @Chubsdad no, the C++ tag is for C++, the C++XX tags are for question that are specific that XX version of C++. It's that simple

Comment: Seems strange that you qualified `vector` but not `string`. Let's promote some consistency!

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the output operator to convert the booleans to whatever you want:

```
ostream& operator<<(const ostream& os, const bool& value) {
    return os << (value ? "1" : "0");
}
```

Then copy the array to a `stringstream`:

```
int main() {
    // ...
    ostringstream oss;
    copy(data, data+size, ostream_iterator<bool>(oss));

    oss.str(); // this is the string you're looking for
    // ...
}
```